# How to execute a bash script from within python in a non-blocking way, and allowing to see its output?

Tags: python, linux, bash

On a Ubuntu Linux system I want to start a bash script from within a python script. I need to run it in a non-blocking way so that the python script reports all output from the bash script to the standard output.

I have found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python) which does not work for me (of course). Here is my bash script `testbash.sh` which just prints a row of numbers:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0

while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
  echo Number: $i
  ((i++))
  sleep 1
done
```

Here is the python script:

```
import sys
import time
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading  import Thread

try:
    from queue import Queue, Empty
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue, Empty  # python 2.x


ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line)
    out.close()

p = Popen(['.','testbash.sh'], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX, shell=True)
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
t.start()

# read line without blocking
running = True
while running:
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        line = q.get_nowait() # or q.get(timeout=.1)
    except Empty:
        print('no output yet')
    else:
        # got line
        print(line)
```

When running this script, I only get the output 'no output yet' and no actual output from the bash script.

I want the python script to run as long as the bash script runs, redirecting the output from the bash script to the python standard-output (so that I see the numbers 1..10 in like every 1-2 seconds), and after ~10 seconds the python script stops. I also need to check if the bash script did finish fine or with an error

What am I missing? Is the script actually running? How to get its output? How to check the exit code?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe better to use sleep command in bash

Comment: I do? Also I updated the question

Comment: Try `Popen(['./testbash.sh','testbash.sh'],`... or simply `Popen('./testbash.sh',`... The first argument is the program to run. Your original program tries to run `'.'` which is the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes need to be made, in particular, the calling of shell script:

```
import sys
import time
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading  import Thread

try:
    from queue import Queue, Empty
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue, Empty  # python 2.x


ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line.decode('ascii'))
    out.close()

p = Popen(['./testbash.sh'], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX, shell=True)
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
t.start()

# read line without blocking
while t.is_alive():
    time.sleep(1)
    try:
        line = q.get_nowait() # or q.get(timeout=.1)
    except Empty:
        print('no output')
    else:
        # got line
        print(line, end='')

p.wait()
print(f'returncode = {p.returncode}')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fixes - is there a way to get the exit status of the bash script?

Comment: Updated, at the end